# Why don't we use cross cut discs for all cuts?

Tags: circular-saw, saw-blade, rip-cut

Most circular saws, at least low and mid ends, come with low/medium quality rip cut discs. They work decent when doing rip cuts but show their limits when doing cross cuts. A lot of tear out on some of them.

There are available high quality cross cut blades.

What if one would use these for rip cuts too? Would this be a bad thing? (inefficient, dangerous etc)

Comment: Using a crosscut blade for rips will be quite slow.  The gullets are not big enough to clear out the waste effectively.  It sounds like you should get a combination blade.  These are essentially crosscut blades with one tooth out of every 4 or 5 filed flat for ripping with a big gullet in front of it.

Comment: Yep, a crosscut blade rips beautifully, but slowly. On an active construction site, taking 2-3 times as long for each cut seriously affects productivity.